# Send mail once content approval of custom content types

Tags: 7

I am creating one Like job posting custom content type.The permission for only posting the job for recruiter.After Post the job I need the approval for publishing permission from admin. My thought when recruiter post the job i want to send the mail like recruiter post the new job for admin and once admin approved the content. How can i do this

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/rules

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hard to understand what you want but I think you should use the "Rules" module, which allows you to "to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events":
https://drupal.org/project/rules

Answer (score 0):

Actually it sounds like you need to use the [Modr8](https://drupal.org/project/modr8) module.

With the module activated, you can set the publishing options for the Job Posting content type to *In moderation queue* and let your admin approve the post.

You can configure the modr8 module to send email notifications to the author when the posting is approved, or if it is held in moderation with a note to author by the admin.

The author can still view and edit the post, but it is not available for general viewing untill it has been approved and removed from the moderation queue.